# Simple LDAP Login: Simple LDAP Login could not authenticate your credentials - Simple LDAP Plugin

Tags: wordpress, ldap, openldap

I have installed the `Simple LDAP Plugin` on my WordPress website at localhost. It's working fine. When I moved this website to live server. it gives the following error.

> Simple LDAP Login: Simple LDAP Login could not authenticate your
>   credentials. The security settings do not permit trying the WordPress
>   user database as a fallback.

I googled it and doesn't get any solution related to this issue.

Using:

```
PHP 5.6.40
```

Machine:

```
Centos
```

I am understood why this issue is coming on the live server. while it's working on local machine.

Is there any permission issue or any module need to install?

Comment: Assuming the configuration is the same both on the test and live server, verify that the live server has appropriate connectivity to the LDAP directory (e.g. "nmap -P0 -p636 LDAPServer.example.com" if you are using LDAPS on the default port, otherwise replace 636 with the appropriate port number)

Comment: Thanks, @LisaJ It has been fixed. Actually the issue in IP Address.